# html from xml using xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am new to xslt and am trying to create html from xml using xslt.

I dont know why but my xslt works when only one element is there but not when multiple.

I tried various ways but as said i am new to this and am not sure how to do this any more.

Here is my xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<DestinationResults size="1">
<Destination name="Paris, FRA" order="1">
<HotelAvailabilityListResults size="10">
<Hotel order="1">
<hotelId>188139</hotelId>
<name>
<![CDATA[ Hotel Magenta Paris ]]>
</name>
<address1>38 Boulevard De Magenta</address1>
<address2/>
<address3/>
<city>Paris</city>
<stateProvince/>
<country>FR</country>
<postalCode>75010</postalCode>
<latitude>48.87203</latitude>
<longitude>2.35995</longitude>
<tripAdvisorRating>4.0</tripAdvisorRating>
<fromDate>10/11/2013</fromDate>
<toDate>10/12/2013</toDate>
<shortDescription>
<![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Property Location&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;With a stay at Hotel Magenta Paris in Paris (Gare du Nord - Gare de L&apos;Est), you&apos;ll be minutes from Porte Saint-Martin and close to Louvre Museum. This]]>
</shortDescription>
<thumbNailUrl>
http://origin-images.ian.com/hotels/1000000/890000/889000/888903/888903_22_t.jpg
</thumbNailUrl>
<propertyRating>3.0</propertyRating>
<referenceProximityDistance>-1.0</referenceProximityDistance>
<referenceProximityUnit/>
<HotelProperty>
<promoDescription>Stay 1 nights and save 10% off your stay!</promoDescription>
<ValueAdds>
<valueAdd id="2048">Free Wireless Internet</valueAdd>
</ValueAdds>
<PromoRateInfo>
<displayCurrencyCode>USD</displayCurrencyCode>
<DisplayNightlyRates size="1">
<displayNightlyRate>152.02</displayNightlyRate>
</DisplayNightlyRates>
<displayRoomRate>168.68</displayRoomRate>
<chargeableRoomRateTotal>168.68</chargeableRoomRateTotal>
<chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>16.66</chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>
<taxesOnly>16.66</taxesOnly>
<salesTax>0</salesTax>
<hotelOccupancyTax>0</hotelOccupancyTax>
<nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
<NativeNightlyRates size="1">
<nativeNightlyRate>152.02</nativeNightlyRate>
</NativeNightlyRates>
<nativeRoomRate>168.68</nativeRoomRate>
<rateFrequency>B</rateFrequency>
</PromoRateInfo>
<RateInfo>
<displayCurrencyCode>USD</displayCurrencyCode>
<DisplayNightlyRates size="1">
<displayNightlyRate>168.91</displayNightlyRate>
</DisplayNightlyRates>
<displayRoomRate>185.57</displayRoomRate>
<chargeableRoomRateTotal>185.57</chargeableRoomRateTotal>
<chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>16.66</chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>
<taxesOnly>16.66</taxesOnly>
<salesTax>0</salesTax>
<hotelOccupancyTax>0</hotelOccupancyTax>
<nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
<NativeNightlyRates size="1">
<nativeNightlyRate>168.91</nativeNightlyRate>
</NativeNightlyRates>
<nativeRoomRate>185.57</nativeRoomRate>
<rateFrequency>B</rateFrequency>
</RateInfo>
</HotelProperty>
<hotelUrl>
http://booking.rated-hotels.co.uk/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&cid=409870&hotelID=188139&mode=2&numberOfRooms=1&room-0-adult-total=2&room-0-child-total=0&arrivalMonth=9&arrivalDay=11&departureMonth=9&departureDay=12&showInfo=true&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&mcicid=409870.HOTEL.XML.85419
</hotelUrl>
</Hotel>
<Hotel order="2">
<hotelId>188140</hotelId>
<name>
<![CDATA[ Hotel Magenta Paris ]]>
</name>
<address1>38 Boulevard De Magenta</address1>
<address2/>
<address3/>
<city>Paris</city>
<stateProvince/>
<country>FR</country>
<postalCode>75010</postalCode>
<latitude>48.87203</latitude>
<longitude>2.35995</longitude>
<tripAdvisorRating>4.0</tripAdvisorRating>
<fromDate>10/11/2013</fromDate>
<toDate>10/12/2013</toDate>
<shortDescription>
<![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Property Location&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;With a stay at Hotel Magenta Paris in Paris (Gare du Nord - Gare de L&apos;Est), you&apos;ll be minutes from Porte Saint-Martin and close to Louvre Museum. This]]>
</shortDescription>
<thumbNailUrl>
http://origin-images.ian.com/hotels/1000000/890000/889000/888903/888903_22_t.jpg
</thumbNailUrl>
<propertyRating>3.0</propertyRating>
<referenceProximityDistance>-1.0</referenceProximityDistance>
<referenceProximityUnit/>
<HotelProperty>
<promoDescription>Stay 1 nights and save 10% off your stay!</promoDescription>
<ValueAdds>
<valueAdd id="2048">Free Wireless Internet</valueAdd>
</ValueAdds>
<PromoRateInfo>
<displayCurrencyCode>USD</displayCurrencyCode>
<DisplayNightlyRates size="1">
<displayNightlyRate>152.02</displayNightlyRate>
</DisplayNightlyRates>
<displayRoomRate>168.68</displayRoomRate>
<chargeableRoomRateTotal>168.68</chargeableRoomRateTotal>
<chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>16.66</chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>
<taxesOnly>16.66</taxesOnly>
<salesTax>0</salesTax>
<hotelOccupancyTax>0</hotelOccupancyTax>
<nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
<NativeNightlyRates size="1">
<nativeNightlyRate>152.02</nativeNightlyRate>
</NativeNightlyRates>
<nativeRoomRate>168.68</nativeRoomRate>
<rateFrequency>B</rateFrequency>
</PromoRateInfo>
<RateInfo>
<displayCurrencyCode>USD</displayCurrencyCode>
<DisplayNightlyRates size="1">
<displayNightlyRate>168.91</displayNightlyRate>
</DisplayNightlyRates>
<displayRoomRate>185.57</displayRoomRate>
<chargeableRoomRateTotal>185.57</chargeableRoomRateTotal>
<chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>16.66</chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>
<taxesOnly>16.66</taxesOnly>
<salesTax>0</salesTax>
<hotelOccupancyTax>0</hotelOccupancyTax>
<nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
<NativeNightlyRates size="1">
<nativeNightlyRate>168.91</nativeNightlyRate>
</NativeNightlyRates>
<nativeRoomRate>185.57</nativeRoomRate>
<rateFrequency>B</rateFrequency>
</RateInfo>
</HotelProperty>
<hotelUrl>
http://booking.rated-hotels.co.uk/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&cid=409870&hotelID=188139&mode=2&numberOfRooms=1&room-0-adult-total=2&room-0-child-total=0&arrivalMonth=9&arrivalDay=11&departureMonth=9&departureDay=12&showInfo=true&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&mcicid=409870.HOTEL.XML.85419
</hotelUrl>
</Hotel>


</HotelAvailabilityListResults>
</Destination>
</DestinationResults>
```

and my xslt is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">

<xsl:for-each select="DestinationResults">
<xsl:for-each select="Destination">
<xsl:for-each select="HotelAvailabilityListResults">
<xsl:for-each select="Hotel">





      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>
        - <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="shortDescription"/>.
        <span style="font-style:italic">
          <xsl:value-of select="address1"/> 
        </span>.</p>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>

  </body>
</html>
```

This xslt works for the above xml but when there are multiple Hotel orders in xml like below then the xslt does not produce any results.

```
<Hotel order="2">
    <hotelId>188139</hotelId>
    <name>
    <![CDATA[ Hotel Magenta Paris ]]>
    </name>
    <address1>38 Boulevard De Magenta</address1>
    <address2/>
    <address3/>
    <city>Paris</city>
    <stateProvince/>
    <country>FR</country>
    <postalCode>75010</postalCode>
    <latitude>48.87203</latitude>
    <longitude>2.35995</longitude>
    <tripAdvisorRating>4.0</tripAdvisorRating>
    <fromDate>10/11/2013</fromDate>
    <toDate>10/12/2013</toDate>
    <shortDescription>
    <![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Property Location&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;With a stay at Hotel Magenta Paris in Paris (Gare du Nord - Gare de L&apos;Est), you&apos;ll be minutes from Porte Saint-Martin and close to Louvre Museum. This]]>
    </shortDescription>
    <thumbNailUrl>
    http://origin-images.ian.com/hotels/1000000/890000/889000/888903/888903_22_t.jpg
    </thumbNailUrl>
    <propertyRating>3.0</propertyRating>
    <referenceProximityDistance>-1.0</referenceProximityDistance>
    <referenceProximityUnit/>
    <HotelProperty>
    <promoDescription>Stay 1 nights and save 10% off your stay!</promoDescription>
    <ValueAdds>
    <valueAdd id="2048">Free Wireless Internet</valueAdd>
    </ValueAdds>
    <PromoRateInfo>
    <displayCurrencyCode>USD</displayCurrencyCode>
    <DisplayNightlyRates size="1">
    <displayNightlyRate>152.02</displayNightlyRate>
    </DisplayNightlyRates>
    <displayRoomRate>168.68</displayRoomRate>
    <chargeableRoomRateTotal>168.68</chargeableRoomRateTotal>
    <chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>16.66</chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>
    <taxesOnly>16.66</taxesOnly>
    <salesTax>0</salesTax>
    <hotelOccupancyTax>0</hotelOccupancyTax>
    <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
    <NativeNightlyRates size="1">
    <nativeNightlyRate>152.02</nativeNightlyRate>
    </NativeNightlyRates>
    <nativeRoomRate>168.68</nativeRoomRate>
    <rateFrequency>B</rateFrequency>
    </PromoRateInfo>
    <RateInfo>
    <displayCurrencyCode>USD</displayCurrencyCode>
    <DisplayNightlyRates size="1">
    <displayNightlyRate>168.91</displayNightlyRate>
    </DisplayNightlyRates>
    <displayRoomRate>185.57</displayRoomRate>
    <chargeableRoomRateTotal>185.57</chargeableRoomRateTotal>
    <chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>16.66</chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>
    <taxesOnly>16.66</taxesOnly>
    <salesTax>0</salesTax>
    <hotelOccupancyTax>0</hotelOccupancyTax>
    <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
    <NativeNightlyRates size="1">
    <nativeNightlyRate>168.91</nativeNightlyRate>
    </NativeNightlyRates>
    <nativeRoomRate>185.57</nativeRoomRate>
    <rateFrequency>B</rateFrequency>
    </RateInfo>
    </HotelProperty>
    <hotelUrl>
    http://booking.rated-hotels.co.uk/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&cid=409870&hotelID=188139&mode=2&numberOfRooms=1&room-0-adult-total=2&room-0-child-total=0&arrivalMonth=9&arrivalDay=11&departureMonth=9&departureDay=12&showInfo=true&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&mcicid=409870.HOTEL.XML.85419
    </hotelUrl>
    </Hotel>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Jai

Comment: your select="TagName" attributes are likely to match nothing if the root tag of the data xml changes, you must account for that. possibly adding a template match="//Hotel" directly inside your body tag could fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Writing nested for-each instructions is the most common mistake made by beginners in XSLT. This isn't the way to do it: start by using template rules, and only use for-each when you understand the language well enough to know the cases where it's useful.

Of course in this case you could also simplify the code by using a path:

```
<xsl:for-each select="DestinationResults/Destination/HotelAvailabilityListResults/Hotel">
```

Debugging problems like this requires a clear understanding of the XML tree structure, and it would be much easier to obtain that understanding if you indented the XML properly. I'm not sure what you mean by "multiple Hotel orders" - I only see one order in your second example. Perhaps the problem is that your second example doesn't have the DestinationResults/Destination/HotelAvailabilityListResults wrapper elements which your stylesheet is assuming; at any rate, if they are there then you haven't shown them. Putting the code in a template rule with match="Hotel" would avoid this dependency on what's present in the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the information.I did not want to add the whole XML sheet in here. So assuming  Ihave multiple hotel orders

Comment: I can understand why you don't want to include the whole XML. Unfortunately, not including it means we can't see what's wrong. The answer is to reduce the problem to a size where everything necessary to reproduce the problem is present, but we don't have to wade through pages of irrelevant detail.

Comment: I understand I have included the XML for two hotel orders and this is the issue here . So in XML there are multiple hotel orders and my xslt does not work.

Hope this helps. Your help is much appreciated.